# Order by two meta ACF Fields in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I try sorting products (no Woocommerce, but created by custom post_type) in my site by price. I have two Advanced Custom Fields = `price` and `price_sale`.
I need result like this:

- 1999$
- 2222$ (price_sale) 4000$
- 3200$ (price_sale) 3600$
- 3500$

I have this query arguments:

```
 {
        "categories": "sofas",
        "meta_query": {
           "relation": "AND",
           "1":{
              "relation": "AND",
              "query_one": {
                 "key": "price",
                 "type": "NUMERIC"
              },
              "query_two": {
                 "key": "price_sale",
                 "type": "NUMERIC"
              }
           }
        },
        "orderby": {
           "query_two": "ASC",
           "query_one": "ASC"
        }
     }
```

And result - all promotional products go after the usual while being sorted by price, like this:

- 1999$
- 3500$
- 2222$ (price_sale) 4000$
- 3200$ (price_sale) 3600$

I need them to sort through the two fields and displaying like as first example above.

Comment: Why not sorting them afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest was is to sort them after querying. However, you can achieve it by using this alternative, so that you won't have to sort by your own afterwards:

Add a filter on `post_orderby` [WP Codex post_orderby](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) Using this you could implement a sorting function which joins the both sorted sub-queries and resorts them.

I don't see another chance.